# URL search link for 'category__and' instead of php query

Tags: search

I found this in the WP Docs:

*Display posts that are in multiple categories. This shows posts that are in both categories 2 and 6:
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category__and' => array( 2, 6 ) ) );*

Is there a way to replicate this type of search via a direct search URL in the browser, so I can just link to the results instead of having to create a php file?

I am not really a developer so I apologize if this question is rudimentary.

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for (I'm curious what the answer here is too). Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.